# Converting USB printer to wifi printer using wifi adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I have a printer with USB cable. If I connect it to USB female to female coupler, and then connect a usb wifi adapter, would that work?

I am looking for a cheaper and simpler alternative to buying a printer server or not using raspberry pi. I also do not have the option to plugin the printer cable to wifi router.

Printer -> Coupler -> Wifi adapter
I am thinking of these 2 devices.

[https://www.amazon.com/Connector-Adapter-Extension-Coupler-SuperSpeed/dp/B07FT9MDX4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FT9MDX4)
[https://www.amazon.com/TP-Link-wireless-network-Adapter-SoftAP/dp/B008IFXQFU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008IFXQFU)

Comment: The WiFi adapter you are asking about will only work with USB hosts.  Your USB printer is not considered to be a USB host.  If the printer you have does not have wireless capability there is no way to connect to it without connecting to it directly or sharing it over a network.

Answer (score 1):

What you suggest is unlikely to work as you expect. Your USB printer is configured as a connection in which the printer is the peripheral device. The USB wifi adapter is configured as a connection to a controlling device. Regardless of the gender of the connections, there will not be appropriate communications available.

You suggest that you cannot connect the printer cable to a wifi router. Wifi implies wireless, which means without wires or cables.

If your printer has a wired network connection capability but is too far away to plug into a router, you may consider a [wired to wireless adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014SK2H6W).

This device connects to the wired port on your printer and requires external power to the usb (power-only) connection. When properly configured, it will then communicate to the wifi router to provide the communication you require for your printer.

[image: wired to wireless adapter]